# .htaccess redirect all pages of old site to same pages on a subdirectory of a different site

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, subdirectory

I need to redirect all pages of an old site to a subdirectory of our main site. E.g.:

`oldsite.com/page1`
to
`mainsite.com/oldsite/page1`

I have tried adding the following to the top of .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

  RewriteEngine On

  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^oldsite.com$ 

  RewriteCond (.*)$ http://www.mainsite.com/oldsite/$1 [R=301,L]

</IfModule>
```

When I open a fresh anonymous window, the redirect does not work, even on the homepage.  So it is probably another rule getting in the way.  The following is at the bottom of the .htaccess file:

```
# BEGIN W3TC Page Cache core
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =on
    RewriteRule .* - [E=W3TC_SSL:_ssl]
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} =443
    RewriteRule .* - [E=W3TC_SSL:_ssl]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} =https [NC]
    RewriteRule .* - [E=W3TC_SSL:_ssl]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Encoding} gzip
    RewriteRule .* - [E=W3TC_ENC:_gzip]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} w3tc_preview [NC]
    RewriteRule .* - [E=W3TC_PREVIEW:_preview]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !=POST
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} =""
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !(comment_author|wp\-postpass|w3tc_logged_out|wordpress_logged_in|wptouch_switch_toggle) [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \/$
    RewriteCond "%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/wp-content/cache/page_enhanced/%{HTTP_HOST}/%{REQUEST_URI}/_index%{ENV:W3TC_SSL}%{ENV:W3TC_PREVIEW}.html%{ENV:W3TC_ENC}" -f
    RewriteRule .* "/wp-content/cache/page_enhanced/%{HTTP_HOST}/%{REQUEST_URI}/_index%{ENV:W3TC_SSL}%{ENV:W3TC_PREVIEW}.html%{ENV:W3TC_ENC}" [L]
</IfModule>
# END W3TC Page Cache core
# BEGIN WordPress
# The directives (lines) between "BEGIN WordPress" and "END WordPress" are
# dynamically generated, and should only be modified via WordPress filters.
# Any changes to the directives between these markers will be overwritten.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_ACCEPT} image/webp
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} (.*)\.(jpe?g|png)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.webp -f
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !type=original
RewriteRule (.+)\.(jpe?g|png)$ %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.webp [T=image/webp,E=accept:1,L]
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
Header append Vary Accept env=REDIRECT_accept
</IfModule>
```

Any ideas on what I should change to achieve my desired result?:
`oldsite.com/page1`
to
`mainsite.com/oldsite/page1`

Comment: The rule you implemented looks fine, though it might pay out to tweak it slightly. So your issue must have another cause. Either there is some additional rule interfering here, a rule you did not show, or you are simply used at redirections cached on the client side, maybe from earlier attempts. Remember to always test using a fresh anonymous browser. Better even start out with `R=302` and only change that to `R=301` once everything works as desired.

Comment: Thank you.  I've edited my question based on your response, since it was too much to fit in the comment character limit.  Can you see anything in the rules that are already in my .htaccess file that would interfere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!

I removed all the rewrite rules that were already in there, apart from the wordpress one.

I then used this rule instead of the one I originally posted:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^oldsite.com$ [NC,OR]
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.oldsite.com$
  RewriteRule (.*)$ http://www.mainsite.com/oldsite/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: So basically the requests went to the host "www.oldsite.com"? You can combine the two conditions: `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)oldsite\.com$`